# connecting SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

i wanted you to give me a hand so i can fix this, i have tried everything already

Example

going to VS 2010 > tools > data connections > leave it blank and type SQLEXPRESS 
also tried to change the machine.config

however it is not working yet

Connections to SQL server database files (.mdf) require sql server 2005 or 2008 to be installed and running on your computer

i've already installed sql server 2008 r2 
please help me!! been having this problem for a long time

Comment: Please [edit] your title to include information about the question itself. "SQL SERVER 2008 R2" is information that belongs in a tag, which means your entire subject boils down to "Issue", and that clearly isn't meaningful to us or to any future reader that might find it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install also 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985

The managment tool in order to connect the DB instace

Comment: Thanks for answering. the SQL SERVER 2008 R2 is full! it has all in fact it was working 1 year ago and i had to reformat my pc , tried to reinstall SQL SERVER and that error came up!